# wildcard redirect with url rewrite by web.config

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config

I'm using the url rewrite features in web.config to redirect my subdomains. Here is my rule :

```
   <rule name="redirect_page">
      <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false" negate="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\." negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^([\w\-]+)\.mySite\.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="profile.aspx?name={C:1}" />
    </rule>
```

This works great :
http://myUser.mySite.com ***redirect to*** http://myUser.mySite.com/profile.aspx?name=myUser

BUT

http://myUser.mySite.com/image/myImage.jpg ***redirect to*** http://myUser.mySite.com/profile.aspx?name=myUser

=> What I want :
http://myUser.mySite.com/image/myImage.jpg ***redirect to*** http://myUser.mySite.com/image/myImage.jpg

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is a little tricky but here is the solution :

```
    <rule name="SubDomainDoNothing" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.+)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www)(\w+)\.plugandtable\.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="SubDomainRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www)(\w+)\.plugandtable\.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="profile.aspx?name={C:1}" />
    </rule>
```